# ASP MVC 2 Dynamic Href By Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is the deal:

My link:

```
<li><% =Html.ActionLink("Scheme", null, null, null, new { @id = "schemeid" })%></li>
```

JavaScript for changing href:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('schemeid').href= "Test/ALL";
</script>
```

Its working in any browser on ASP.NET dev.server on vs2010;
but when i host it on iis 7. it fails. and in source of web page i have href=""

can any one help?

Comment: Isn't the second (or third?) parameter in that overload supposed to be "Controller" ?

Comment: Where in the page is this script block located?

Comment: 1. yes supposed. but itwhen i write test/all that means test-controller, all-action.
2. in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try using Firefox and check "Console Errors" to see if you got any javascript error. Second, try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('schemeid').href= "Test/ALL";
    });
</script>
```

You'll need jQuery. Maybe your script is executing before rendering the  tag.

Comment: thx. but.
firebug doesnt show anything. and jquery didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

found solution. thx to every body. here is answer:

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='<% =Html.ActionLink("Scheme","ALL","Test")%>';

<li id="list"><% =Html.ActionLink("Scheme", null, null)%></li>
```