# ASP MVC 2 Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I have code on javascript:

```
<script>var index=0</script>
```

How can i pass it to htmlhelper

forexample i want something like:

```
<%Html.ActionLink("test",'+index+',"Stations")%>';
```

but its obvious doesn't work;

Comment: Isn't this the same question as another one of yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541918/asp-mvc-2-dynamic-href-by-javascript/3542047#3542047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a javascript variable to an HTML helper because this helper is evaluated on the server side. You will need to use javascript to manipulate the resulting link and append the `index` variable to the `href`.